ValueError Arising from Tkinter Entry
I am working on a poker game using Tkinter for the UI. Right now, when the first player folds on a round, it causes a Value Error, saying that the entry does not have a value passed in even though I am passing a bet in. Here is the screenshot of me placing the bet:
And I get a value error when trying to process the bet(done by pressing the button underneath the entry).
Here is the code snippet pertaining to the betting :
def startBetting():
    '''Counts the money in the pot and the money for each player'''
    global hasRaised, entry, hasBet
    hasRaised = []
    bet_entryList = []
    bet_buttonList = []
    hasBet = False
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        hasRaised.append(False)
        has_folded.append(False)
        # currentBets.append(0)
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        if has_folded[i]:
            continue
        elif money[i] == 0:
            message = messagebox.showwarning("showwarning", "You do not have any money to bet")
            continue
        else:
            if not hasRaised[i]:
                entry = Entry(canvas)
                entry.place(x = button_list[i * 2].winfo_x(), y = button_list[i*2].winfo_y() + 200)
                bet_entryList.append(entry)
                button = tkinter.Button(canvas, text = "Submit a Raise, Call or Fold", command = lambda index = i: [trackMoney(bet_entryList[index].get(), index), bet_entryList[index].destroy(), bet_buttonList[index].destroy()])
                bet_buttonList.append(button)
                button.place(x = button_list[i*2].winfo_x(), y = button_list[i*2].winfo_y() + 275)
            else:
                entry = Entry(canvas)
                entry.place(x = button_list[i * 2].winfo_x(), y = button_list[i*2].winfo_y() + 200)
                bet_entryList.append(entry)
                button = tkinter.Button(canvas, text = "Submit a Call or Fold", command = lambda index = i: [trackMoney(bet_entryList[index].get(), index), bet_entryList[index].destroy(), bet_buttonList[index].destroy()])
                bet_buttonList.append(button)
                button.place(x = button_list[i*2].winfo_x(), y = button_list[i*2].winfo_y() + 275)

Here is the code to the entire game. To recreate the issue below, start a game by giving the amount of players and buy in, press the card image to deal the hands and have the first player fold while the other players make a bet by pressing the 'Bets for the round' button. When you press that button again to collect the bets for the next round, the error will show up when trying to enter a bet. I am not sure how to fix this and any help would be greatly appreciated.
import poker
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import Entry
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from treys import Evaluator
from treys import Card
import random
import numpy as np

deck = list(poker.Card)
random.shuffle(deck)
cards = []
board = []
image_listHand = []
image_listBoard = []
button_list = []
back_imageList = []
money = []
has_folded = []
handCount = 0
boardCount = 0
boardButtonPressCount = 0
currentPot = 0
currentBets = []
#Getting the necessary card for the hand

def changeCardHand():
    card = deck.pop()
    return card

#Getting the necessary card for the board 
def changeCardBoard():
    global board 
    card = deck.pop()
    if len(board) < 5:
        board.append(card)
    return card

#Converting into the name for card searching
def convert_To_Words(suit):
    match suit:
        case "♣":
            return "clubs"
        case "♦":
            return"diamonds"
        case "♥":
            return "hearts"
        case "♠":
            return "spades"

#Converting into letter to use eval library 
def convert_to_Letter(suit):
    match suit:
        case "♣":
            return "c"
        case "♦":
            return "d"
        case "♥":
            return "h"
        case "♠":
            return "s" 

#displaying the card by finding the image
def showCard(suit, rank, width, height):
    '''Returns the necessary image '''
    suit = convert_To_Words(suit)
    image = Image.open(f"PNG-cards-1.3/{rank}_of_{suit}.png")
    image = image.resize((width, height))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    return image



#change spacing with the amount of people playing so it works better

#This deals the card to each of the players
def dealCard():
    '''Deals the Card to Each of the players'''
    global handCount, cards, cardSuit, cardRank, hand
    for i in range(amountOfPlayers):
        hand = []
        while handCount < 2:
            card = changeCardHand()
            cardSuit = str(card.suit)
            cardRank = str(card.rank)
            cardImage = showCard(cardSuit, cardRank, width= 75, height = 100)
            image_listHand.append(cardImage)
            backImage = Image.open(f"PNG-cards-1.3/card_back_black.png")
            backImage = backImage.resize((75, 100))
            backImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(backImage)
            back_imageList.append(backImage)
            cardButton = tkinter.Button(canvas, image = backImage, text = getPlayerMoney(i), compound = "top", command = lambda index = image_listHand.index(cardImage): [flipImage(index)])
            button_list.append(cardButton)
            cardButton.place(x = (-16 * amountOfPlayers) + (55*(2*i+1) + 125*(i + 1)) + (handCount + 1)*80, y = (300))
            handCount = handCount + 1
            hand.append(card)
        cards.append(hand)
        handCount = 0



def setBoard():
    '''Method that sets the board'''
    global boardCount, board, cardSuit, cardRank, boardButtonPressCount
    while boardCount < 3 and boardButtonPressCount < 1:
        card = changeCardBoard()
        cardSuit = str(card.suit)
        cardRank = str(card.rank)
        cardImage = showCard(cardSuit, cardRank, width= 75, height = 100)
        image_listBoard.append(cardImage)
        canvas.create_image(500 + boardCount*100, 130, image = cardImage)
        boardCount = boardCount + 1
    while boardCount < 4 and boardButtonPressCount < 2 and boardButtonPressCount >= 1:
        card = changeCardBoard()
        cardSuit = str(card.suit)
        cardRank = str(card.rank)
        cardImage = showCard(cardSuit, cardRank, width= 75, height = 100)
        image_listBoard.append(cardImage)
        canvas.create_image(500 + boardCount*100, 130, image = cardImage)
        boardCount = boardCount + 1
    while boardCount < 5 and boardButtonPressCount < 3 and boardButtonPressCount >=2:
        card = changeCardBoard()
        cardSuit = str(card.suit)
        cardRank = str(card.rank)
        cardImage = showCard(cardSuit, cardRank, width= 75, height = 100)
        image_listBoard.append(cardImage)
        canvas.create_image(500 + boardCount*100, 130, image = cardImage)
        boardCount = boardCount + 1
    boardButtonPressCount = boardButtonPressCount + 1
    

#Method that evaluates the hand and returns the highest value. Can go and find index then find winner
#Make sure that it only goes through cards that are not folded
def evaluateHand():
    '''Method that evaluates the hand and returns the winner.'''
    global evalCard, evalBoard, scores, minScore
    eval = Evaluator()
    evalBoard = []
    scores = []
    minScore = 10000000
    if len(board) == 5 and len(cards)%amountOfPlayers == 0: 
        for card in board:
            a = str(card.rank) + convert_to_Letter(str(card.suit))
            card2 = Card.new(a)
            evalBoard.append(card2)
        for hands in cards:
            for card in hands:
                evalCard = []
                a = str(card.rank) + convert_to_Letter(str(card.suit))
                card2 = Card.new(a)
                evalCard.append(card2)
            scores.append(eval.evaluate(evalCard, evalBoard))
    for i in range(len(scores)):
        if not has_folded[i] and scores[i] < minScore:
            minScore = scores[i]
    message = messagebox.showinfo("showinfo", "Player number " + str(scores.index(minScore)+ 1) + " was the winner with a " + eval.class_to_string(eval.get_rank_class(np.min(scores))))

def getAmountOfPlayers():
    '''Gets the global amount of players'''
    global amountOfPlayers
    amountOfPlayers = int(playerEntry.get())
    playerEntry.destroy()


def flipImage(index):
    '''Flips the Image from backside to rightside'''
    if button_list[index].cget('image') != str(image_listHand[index]):
        button_list[index].config(image = image_listHand[index])
    else:
        button_list[index].config(image = back_imageList[index])

def loadMoney():
    '''Loads the money into each of the players hands'''
    global potValue
    potValue = int(potEntry.get())
    for i in range(amountOfPlayers):
        money.append(potValue)
        currentBets.append(0)
    potEntry.destroy()

#Fix this method by making the entries with one button, and then button spawns under and creates new buttons and stuff like that
def startBetting():
    '''Counts the money in the pot and the money for each player'''
    global hasRaised, entry, hasBet
    hasRaised = []
    bet_entryList = []
    bet_buttonList = []
    hasBet = False
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        hasRaised.append(False)
        has_folded.append(False)
        # currentBets.append(0)
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        if has_folded[i]:
            continue
        elif money[i] == 0:
            message = messagebox.showwarning("showwarning", "You do not have any money to bet")
            continue
        else:
            if not hasRaised[i]:
                entry = Entry(canvas)
                entry.place(x = button_list[i * 2].winfo_x(), y = button_list[i*2].winfo_y() + 200)
                bet_entryList.append(entry)
                button = tkinter.Button(canvas, text = "Submit a Raise, Call or Fold", command = lambda index = i: [trackMoney(bet_entryList[index].get(), index), bet_entryList[index].destroy(), bet_buttonList[index].destroy()])
                bet_buttonList.append(button)
                button.place(x = button_list[i*2].winfo_x(), y = button_list[i*2].winfo_y() + 275)
            else:
                entry = Entry(canvas)
                entry.place(x = button_list[i * 2].winfo_x(), y = button_list[i*2].winfo_y() + 200)
                bet_entryList.append(entry)
                button = tkinter.Button(canvas, text = "Submit a Call or Fold", command = lambda index = i: [trackMoney(bet_entryList[index].get(), index), bet_entryList[index].destroy(), bet_buttonList[index].destroy()])
                bet_buttonList.append(button)
                button.place(x = button_list[i*2].winfo_x(), y = button_list[i*2].winfo_y() + 275)



#Need to fix the trackMoney Method, make new entries and buttons for raise and other stuff 
#need to add checks such that you are not betting more than you have money for
def trackMoney(action, index):
    global hasRaised, currentBets, currentPot
    ''' This method causes the amount of money to be given and collected'''
    if action == "Fold":
        has_folded[index] = True
    else:
        if int(action) + currentBets[index] > currentPot: # Raise
            hasRaised[index] = True
            currentPot = int(action) + currentBets[index]
            money[index] = money[index] - (int(action))
            currentBets[index] = currentPot
        elif int(action) + currentBets[index] == currentPot: # Call
            money[index] = money[index] - (int(action))
            currentBets[index] = currentPot
            
    for index in range(len(image_listHand)):
        button_list[index].config(text = getPlayerMoney(index//2))

    currentMoneyLabel.config(text = "Current Bet " + str(currentPot))
    
    
#need to make a button that gives the winner the current bet amount of money afterwards
def awardWinner():
    global currentPot, scores, money, minScore, amountOfPlayers
    index = scores.index(minScore)
    money[index] = money[index] + currentPot * amountOfPlayers
    for index in range(len(image_listHand)):
        button_list[index].config(text = getPlayerMoney(index//2))



def getPlayerMoney(index):
    return str(money[index])


#Method to check if everyone has either folded or placed a bet
def check():
    global has_folded, currentBets
    for index in range(len(cards)):
        if not has_folded[index] and currentBets[index] == 0:
            return False
    return True

#as well as show ways to transfer money and have continous games

def resetBoard():
    global cards,board, image_listHand, image_listBoard, button_list, back_imageList
    for child in canvas.winfo_children:
        child.destroy()
    deck = list(poker.Card)
    random.shuffle(deck)
    cards.clear()
    board.clear()
    image_listHand.clear()
    image_listBoard.clear()
    button_list.clear()
    back_imageList.clear()
  

   

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1500x1700")
root.title("Poker Game")

deckOfCardImage = Image.open(f"PNG-cards-1.3/card_back_red.png")
deckOfCardImage = deckOfCardImage.resize((100,150))
deckOfCardImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(deckOfCardImage)
deckOfCardButton = tkinter.Button(root, image=deckOfCardImage, command= lambda: [dealCard()])
deckOfCardButton.pack()

dealBoardButton = tkinter.Button(root, text= "Place the board", command = lambda: [setBoard()])
dealBoardButton.place(x = 1020, y = 10)

handEvaluationButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Evaluate your Hand", command =  lambda : [evaluateHand()])
handEvaluationButton.place(x = 1170, y = 10)

playerEntry = Entry(root)
playerEntry.pack()

entryButton= tkinter.Button(root, text = "Entry how many players you want", command = lambda : [getAmountOfPlayers(), entryButton.destroy()])
entryButton.pack()

potEntry = Entry(root)
potEntry.pack()

potButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "What is the buy in value?", command= lambda :[loadMoney(), potButton.destroy()])
potButton.pack()

betButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Bets for the round", command= lambda:[startBetting()])
betButton.place(x = 75, y = 10)

currentMoneyLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text= "Current Pot: " + str(0), padx= 5, pady= 5)
currentMoneyLabel.place(x = 250, y = 10)

awardWinnerButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Pay out for the Round", command = lambda: [awardWinner()])
awardWinnerButton.place(x = 400, y = 10)

resetBoardButton = tkinter.Button(root, text = "Go to next Round", command = lambda: [resetBoard()])
resetBoardButton.place(x = 850, y = 10)


canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width= 1500, height= 1500)

canvas.pack()



root.mainloop()



Normally one would expect you to give MRE - Minimum Reproducible Example - But I guess you are kinda lost on how to do so. Try wrapping repetitive codes (for i.e. inside setBoard() or startBetting()) as other function that gets parameters, so you only have to write once. Do such to reduce lines count, and create copy of the code, then replace image files to something else so people could just copy-paste code and it works. I think it's for the best as you're probably having issue inside your game logic, stripping it down might not be as helpful.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. Don't try to describe what you have in error message but show FULL error message.

error shows you in which line you have problem - and we can't see it - so maybe use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debugging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.
